# How should I configure the properties stored in aws parameter store into micronaut using application.yml

Tags: micronaut, aws-parameter-store, micronaut-aws

I want to use properties from aws parameter store in my micronaut application using the built in micronaut discovery client, but it's not properly documented that how to configure and inject the individual parameters after mentioning the 'rootHierarchyPath'

Here is the application.yml code, I have mentioned the root path
But can't find how to fetch the entries 'dbUserName' and 'dbPassword' stored in the parameter store.

aws:
    client:
        system-manager:
            parameterstore:
                enabled: true
                useSecureParameters: true
                rootHierarchyPath: /application/db

Answer (score 1):

Any configuration resolved from a distributed configuration store is accessible just like any other configuration value. There are many ways of retrieving configuration values. The documentation goes in detail on how to do that https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#config